# Does the game have elements of luck or feng shui?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Apparently, in previous titles of Animal Crossing, there were factors such as luck and feng shui which either increased the chances of positive things happening or negative things happening.

In Animal Crossing New Horizons, is there any gameplay element of luck or feng shui present?  So far I've acquired the ladder, successfully built 3 Villager homes and their decorations, a bridge, and have had Nook's Cranny built. Throughout all that, I don't recall Tom or any other NPC bringing that topic up.  The wiki says that luck is a hidden mechanic, but doesn't specify if it is also present in New Horizons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [there is feng shui](https://game8.co/games/Animal-Crossing-New-Horizons/archives/286199) in New Horizons. In a normal playthrough you would learn this through hints in the Happy Home Academy letters.

[image: Happy Home Academy Letter]

In a nutshell (spoiler ahead):

- The game checks the outermost two slots in your apartment.
- Yellow items should go to the left
- Red items to the right
- Green items to the bottom
- The overlapping fields (bottom left and bottom right) can have any of the two colors

[image: Item Placements]

As for the effects:

- Yellow items increase your luck with regard to Bells (e.g. how much money a resident gives you for a gift)
- Red items, for example, increase your chance of getting valuable items in the shop.
- Green items increase your Overall Luck